# What are the Basic things Require to create project in java

Tags: java

What are the basic things required to Complete a project in Java Language.

Comment: depends on the type of project.

Comment: I would use an IDE rather than a general purpose text editor. While not a requirement it will make development much easier as that is their purpose.

Answer (score 5):

A [text editor](http://www.vim.org/) and a [compiler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

analyzing, designing, coding, testing, user requirement and testing, implementing,

this was now for developing, specific to the java, jdk, editor, like netbeans/eclipse etc.

Answer (score 0):

Donwload the JDK
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html

And follow Oracle Java tutorials for the basics you looking for
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html